# Display different content depending on Referrer

Tags: php

Hey I am trying to display a different phone number for visitors my website from my Google adwords campaign.

The code below works without the else statement (so if I click through to the page from Google it will display a message, and if I visit the site regularly it does not). When I added the else statement it outputs both numbers. Thank you

```
<?php

// The domain list.
$domains = Array('googleadservices.com', 'google.com');

$url_info = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

if (isset($url_info['host'])) {
    foreach($domains as $domain) {

        if (substr($url_info['host'], -strlen($domain)) == $domain) {

            // GOOGLE NUMBER HERE

            echo ('1234');
        }
            // REGULAR NUMBER HERE

        else {
            echo ('12345');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is slightly skewed; you're checking to see if the URL from `parse_url` matches the domains in your array; but you're running through the whole array each time. So you get both a match and a non-match, because `google.com` matches one entry but not the other.

I'd suggest making your domains array into an associative array:

```
$domains = Array('googleadservices.com' => '1234',
                 'google.com' => '12345' );
```

Then you just need to check once:

```
if (isset($url_info['host'])) {
    if (isset($domains[$url_info['host']])) {
         echo $domains[$url_info['host']];
    }
}
```

I've not tested this, but it should be enough for you to see the logic.

(I've also removed the `substr` check - you may need to put that back in, to ensure that you're getting the exact string that you need to look for)

Comment: Hey thanks. My logic is .. if person visits from googleadwords or google - show option a .. else show option b .. Not your reply will help me?

Comment: In that case... You can give both fields in the array the same value, and add an else to the if; so if the referer isn't in the lookup array, you send a default value. That will give you a little extra flexibility to add in additional entries if you ever need to.